# The control voltage output for a phase locked loop

Tags: voltage, control, pll

I am designing a low power phase locked loop in cadence with a phase detector, charge pump and VCO.The control voltage output for my circuit at the output of charge pump is as shown below

[image: Control voltage output]

But when I zoomed into the waveform I saw some oscillations like this

[image: Control voltage when zoomed]

Does this mean that my PLL is not locking properly because I thought, the control voltage must be constant when locked. But, here it is varying for 0.1Vpp. So how should I interpret my result? Is it right or wrong? Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your oscillator frequency anywhere near 1.3GHz by any chance?

Comment: Yes, the VCO frequency is from 900MHz to 1.33GHz

Comment: I count about 13 cycles per 10nS. The frequency at the PSD doesn't happen to be around 1.3GHz does it? If so, that's entirely what I would expect for a plain PLL without explicit HF filtering. It would help to post a schematic of what you have.

Comment: I wanted to post the schematic, but I couldn't. https://madfeekree.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/basic-introduction-of-phase-locked-loop-pll/   The control voltage from the charge pump is the voltage control to the VCO. So depending on the voltage the frequency of VCO varies from 900MHz to 1.33GHz. What I have shown is the control voltage input itself.

Comment: Then that waveform is merely the reaction of the charge pump to each cycle of the VCO. Your loop filter will eliminate this signal, unless it has a GHz+ bandwidth. It looks like there are lower frequency components superimposed on it, though, and they may be a bigger concern.

Answer (score 1):

To properly design a PLL from scratch requires , understanding of Loop transfer functions of each element and closed loop under various conditions.

Lock-up time, Jitter reduction of clock. Phase Margin. bode Plot, lead-lag compensation filter. 2nd, 3rd or 4th order. ( See Analog devices jitter reducing PLL clocks)

Phase detector gain and limitation with frequency error, test methods of measure phase margin and stress conditions: data patterns, SNR, Temp, voltage

There is more but you have successfully detected your phase error as a control voltage ripple from charge pump filter.

The first step should be to define your design goals and specs, then validate.

**Then you can decide if it is right or wrong!**

**I think it can be improved.** But you can use V/MHz and integrate V to get phase jitter over the time 8n interval of Vc for vco, but don't stop there.

Answer (score 0):

Variation in the VCO control voltage will of course cause variation in the VCO frequency.

However, variations *at the PSD rate* only cause harmonic sidebands, indistinguishable from ordinary harmonic distortion, and we rarely rely on or expect the VCO itself to be harmonic free.